# How to correctly compile this function with numba?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am trying to use numba to compile a relatively simple recursive function that produces a matrix by computing each row as a linear combination of the previous rows, which I express as an inner product with a vector `vec` truncated to the required length:

```py
    @numba.jit("float64[:,:](float64[:], int32)")
    def r(vec, J):
        t = np.empty([len(vec), J], dtype=np.float64) # final matrix has shape len(vec) x J
        t[0] = vec[0]*np.arange(J) # first row
        for i in range(1, len(vec)):
            t[i] = np.sum(vec[:i, None]*t[:i], axis=0)
        return t

    >>> "NumbaWarning: Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled 
        because Function "r" failed type inference due to: Invalid use of
        Function(<built-in function empty>) with argument(s) of type(s):
        (list(int64), dtype=class(float64))"
```

I'm not sure if it's because I am not using the type features in `jit` correctly, or because Numba doesn't like how I wrote the function.

Comment: `np.empty` takes a tuple input, not list.  Try `t = np.empty((len(vec), J), dtype=np.float64)`

Comment: Wow, good catch. Although I now get a different warning: "Invalid use of Function(<built-in function getitem>) with argument(s) of type(s): (array(float64, 1d, A), (slice<a:b>, none))", in the part `vec[:i, None]`

Comment: Ah, solved it! I had to use `np.expand_dims` rather than None, and to specify `int64` instead of `int32`